# WinRT XAML ScrollViewer/ListView rendering huge list doesn't work on device

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml

Starting with following code

```
<Grid>
    <ScrollViewer>
        <ListView Name="listview" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource list}}" />                   
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

I've huge list for winrt app around 1k items. it takes too much time to scroll so I've implemented scroll to top and bottom functionality.

```
listview.SelectedIndex 
listview.UpdateLayout();
listview.ScrollIntoView(SelectedItem);
```

All this works fine on a simulator having around 1000 items in the `ListView`. but when I run the app with Surface device this method doesn't work. It actually fails and paints black rectangles while trying to render `ListView`.

I've just wasted my two days on it. I tried many things but no luck. Can someone tell me how can I handle long list using `ScrollViewer` having a `ListView` and using MVVM on Surface device itself. Simply put smooth scrolling on Surface device with a list of beyond 1000 while moving start to end programmatically.

PS: implementing search is not the option.

Comment: Did you look into UI and data virtualisation? There are some requirements for these mechanisms to work. Also incremental loading is likely needed in you case. Refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx

Comment: @NoxNoctis I've tried many things including visualization samples which run as standalone but too complex to fit into mvvm and my current implementation. can you kindly. share some code snippet re current structure including incremental loading

Comment: Well, I'm *not* sure this will help you out, but it did help me in a similar case. It also adds complexity, as you can not just populate the whole list at once. Use a collection that implements `ISupportIncrementalLoading` for binding and set `DataFetchSize` and `IncrementalLoadingThreshold` for your ListView. I use a wrapper for that: https://github.com/Aurora12/uwputils/blob/master/IncrementalCollection.cs

Comment: But it could also be that your items are not virtualizing and/or they are way too complex, so the framework fails to render items in time. This could happen for a variety of reasons. Are you using template selector? This would prevent virtualization. Is you item data structure concise? Property convertors also add overhead.

Comment: I don't think this question has anything to do with WinRT XAML Toolkit.

Comment: @NoxNoctis yes I'm using template selector, how can i work around it? any chance of still keeping it and still having it virtualising

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should remove the outer ScrollViewer because that breaks virtualization. Other than that there's a limit on the size of the panels you can scroll to about 2 million pixels high/wide. After that you will see rendering issues.

The only way around that is rather complicated and involves writing your own list control from scratch. I don't think anyone has done it yet. Usually if the data is too big - people use other strategies like grouping and expanding groups.